# WPF Custom Control TemplateBinding

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

How do i define a TemplateBinding for my custom control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a little somthing like this..... (btw, this xaml is WPF, not silverlight--which is slightly different)

```
   <style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background={TemplateBinding Background}
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </style>
```

now, once you apply this style to an object, whenever you set the background of that object, the template will use the Background property (this is a property on the button control) and will be defaulted to what you set in the style (in this case, green)

If you want to use a property that does not exsist on the object of your style, you have to derive your own control and add the property as either a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) or use the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.  [Here](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Template_Binding) is a decent explanation for you.

Comment: is that all there is to it? if i want to create my own i just use a setter with a unique name?

Comment: the property must exsist on the object, either as a DependencyProperty or as an INotifyPropertyChanged property.  In this case, Background is a basic property of most controls.

Answer (score 3):

Need a bit more information on what you are trying to do. Setting up a `TemplateBinding` can be done with the following XAML:

`{TemplateBinding YourProperty}`
or

`{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=YourProperty}`

Comment: where do i create the source of this binding and the default value?